# The group of permutations with almost all points fixed is a maximal normal subgroup of the symmetric group.

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, cardinals, symmetric-groups

Let $X$ be an infinite set and let $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ be the symmetric group of $X.$ Let $N$ denote the set of all permutations $\pi\in\operatorname{Sym}(X),$ such that the complement of the set of fixed points of $\pi$ has cardinality strictly less than $\operatorname{card}(X).$

A theorem of Baer is cited in a paper I'm trying to read, which says or implies that $N\lhd \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ and is maximal in the family of normal subgroups of $\operatorname{Sym}(X).$

Baer's paper is in German so I cannot read it. I don't have much trouble with the fact that $N\lhd \operatorname{Sym}(X),$ but the maximality eludes me. Could you please help me with it?

If anyone's interested, the cited paper is

Baer, R., *Die Kompositionsreihe der Gruppe aller eineindeutigen Abbildungen einer unendlichen Menge auf sich*, Studia Math. 5 (1934), 15–17.

Comment: The normal subgroups of $Sym(X)$ are well-known, and can be found in Dixon and Mortimer's book on permutation groups, for example.  Anyway, they are gotten by resticting the cardinality of the non-fixed points, and they are ordered (the same way the cardinality is), so it's not very hard (if you know this!) to see $N$ is maximal normal.

Comment: Scott's group theory also has proofs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This follows from the fact that, if a normal subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(X)$ contains a permutation $\pi$ which moves $\aleph_\nu$ points, then it contains all permutations moving $\aleph_\nu$ or fewer points.  The Baer paper (available [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm5/sm512.pdf)) says very briefly that, in general, this can be proved in the same way as when $\nu=0$ and $X$ is countable; the countable case was proved earlier by Schreier and Ulam (Satz 1, Über die Permutationsgruppe der
natürlichen Zahlenfolge, *Studia Math.* 4, 134-141 (1933), [here.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm4/sm4120.pdf))

A proof of this fact can also be extracted from Dixon and Mortimer's book *Permutation Groups* (Springer, GTM #163, ISBN 0-387-94599-7, $\S 8.1$.)  As with the original Schreier-Ulam proof, it works by starting with $\pi$ and repeatedly conjugating and multiplying, depending on the cycle structure of the permutations being worked with, until one is able to get a permutation with any desired cycle structure.  A sketch of a proof (that is not quite the same as the one in Dixon and Mortimer) is:

- Multiply $\pi$ by a conjugate of itself so as to get an element $\sigma$ with $\aleph_\nu$ 2-cycles, and possibly other cycles.
- Then $\sigma$ is multiplied by a conjugate of itself to get rid of all cycles which are not of length 1 or 2, in such a way as to produce an element $\tau$ of order 2 with $\aleph_\nu$ 2-cycles and $\#X$ fixed points.
- We can multiply $\tau$ by a conjugate of itself to cancel some of these 2-cycles, producing a permutation $\mu_\kappa$ with any number $\kappa\le \aleph_\nu$ of 2-cycles, and $\# X$ fixed points.
- If $\aleph_\nu=\#X$, observe that we can multiply $\mu_{\aleph_\nu}$ by a conjugate of itself to get a permutation $\mu'_\lambda$ with $\#X$ 2-cycles and any number $\lambda\le \#X$ of fixed points.
- The final step is to analyze the cycle structure of any permutation moving $\aleph_\nu$ points or fewer and show that it is a product of two permutations of order 1 or 2, each of which also moves $\aleph_\nu$ points or fewer.  Up to conjugacy, each of those permutations is then either a $\mu_\kappa$ or a $\mu'_\lambda$.